# Shift Command button position to float center

Tags: html, commandbutton, style, styleclass

I have a requirement to shift an apex command button to middle or center position. I can get the feeling that if I can achieve float: center then it would be my desired location for the command button, but over net surfing I get that float : center doesn't work.

Can someone suggest me a way out?

Tried with this also.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" style="margin-top:0; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto;"  onclick="jsApplyFilter();" rerender="pb2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this please :

```
<apex:commandButton title="Click" value="Click" style="width: 100px;position: relative;left: 50%;margin-left: -50px;"/>
```